# How to avoid Cartesian product when merging in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cartesian-product

I want to merge three CSV tables (average speed, traffic flow, car count) in Python to try and build a traffic prediction project using RNNs. However, when I try to merge car count I get a Cartesian product. I assume this happens because, while average speed (405rows) and traffic flow (403rows) files have the same Sensor Names and Timestamps, car count has ~3million rows with different sensor names and timestamps and that's because timestamps in car count are written every few seconds while in average speed and traffic flow they're written every few minutes.

For context these are the columns of all three data files:

```
| Sensor Name | Variable | Units | Timestamp | Value | Location (WKT) | Ground Height Above Sea Level | Sensor Height Above Ground | Broker Name | Third Party | Sensor Centroid Longitude | Sensor Centroid Latitude | Raw ID |
```

And this is the first row of each file:

```
Average Speed:| PER_NE_N05111A | Average Speed | KmPH | 2021-01-11 08:50:00 | 80.0 | LINESTRING (-1.673273114 54.961225752, -1.672295923 54.960841373) | 5.69999980926514 | 2.0 | NE Travel Data API | False | -1.6727845185 | 54.9610335625 | 293 |
```

```
Traffic flow:| PER_NE_N05111A | Traffic Flow | Passenger Car Units | 2021-01-11 08:50:00 | 0.0 | LINESTRING (-1.673273114 54.961225752, -1.672295923 54.960841373) | 5.69999980926514 | 2.0 | NE Travel Data API | False | -1.6727845185 | 54.9610335625 | 293 |
```

```
Car count:PER_PEOPLE_TT2NORTH1 | Car Count | Vehicles | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 0.0 | POINT (-1.476327 54.9731634) | 9.0 | 2.0 | People Counting API | False | -1.476327 | 54.9731634 | 79384
```

As you may notice, all the records except variable, units and value in average speed and traffic flow are the same, however on car count there are not similarities.

Here's the code I've done so far for insertion and preprocessing of the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
aspeed_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/2021_DATA/2021-Average Speed.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4], dtype={'Value': float})
trafficflow_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/2021_DATA/2021-Traffic Flow.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4], dtype={'Value': float})
carcount_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/2021_DATA/2021-Car Count.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4], dtype={'Value': float})

# Convert Timestamp to datetime object
aspeed_df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(aspeed_df['Timestamp'])
trafficflow_df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(trafficflow_df['Timestamp'])
carcount_df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(carcount_df['Timestamp'])

# Set min and max values to be equal of average_speed
min_time = aspeed_df['Timestamp'].min()
max_time = aspeed_df['Timestamp'].max()

# Initialise that the traffic flow and car count start and end with approx
# values of average_speed
trafficflow_df = trafficflow_df[trafficflow_df['Timestamp'] >= min_time]
trafficflow_df = trafficflow_df[trafficflow_df['Timestamp'] <= max_time]
carcount_df = carcount_df[carcount_df['Timestamp'] >= min_time]
carcount_df = carcount_df[carcount_df['Timestamp'] <= max_time]

# Create bins for 5-minute intervals
bin_size = '5T'  # 5 minutes
aspeed_df['Time_Bin'] = pd.cut(aspeed_df['Timestamp'], pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq=bin_size), right=False)
trafficflow_df['Time_Bin'] = pd.cut(trafficflow_df['Timestamp'], pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq=bin_size), right=False)
carcount_df['Time_Bin'] = pd.cut(carcount_df['Timestamp'], pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq=bin_size), right=False)

# Merge traffic and congestion data on timestamp
merged_df = pd.merge(aspeed_df, trafficflow_df, on=['Time_Bin'])
merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df, carcount_df, on=['Time_Bin'])

print("Unique sensor names in aspeed_df:", aspeed_df['Sensor Name'].nunique())
print("Unique sensor names in trafficflow_df:", trafficflow_df['Sensor Name'].nunique())
print("Unique sensor names in carcount_df:", carcount_df['Sensor Name'].nunique())

common_sensors = set(aspeed_df['Sensor Name'].unique()) & set(trafficflow_df['Sensor Name'].unique()) & set(carcount_df['Sensor Name'].unique())
print("Common sensor names between all DataFrames:", len(common_sensors))
print("Minimum and maximum timestamps in aspeed_df:", aspeed_df['Timestamp'].min(), aspeed_df['Timestamp'].max())
print("Minimum and maximum timestamps in trafficflow_df:", trafficflow_df['Timestamp'].min(), trafficflow_df['Timestamp'].max())
print("Minimum and maximum timestamps in carcount_df:", carcount_df['Timestamp'].min(), carcount_df['Timestamp'].max())

print(merged_df)
```

As you seen from **# Set min and max values to be equal of average_speed** and downwards, I set the min time and max time to that off average speed so that all three data frames start from similar timestamps ( **# Initialise that the traffic flow and car count start and end with approx values of average_speed** part)and then I made bins with 5-minute intervals which is the case for average speed and traffic flow count and considering that car count timestamps are every few seconds, it would find similar timestamps to those two. And at the end the data frames should be cut accordingly and containing only the relevant information. And finally I try to merge these three files together (and I also added some help info print statements at the end for a better understanding) and this is the result I received:

```
Unique sensor names in aspeed_df: 25
Unique sensor names in trafficflow_df: 25
Unique sensor names in carcount_df: 208
Common sensor names between all DataFrames: 0
Common sensor names between Average spped and Traffic Flow 25
Minimum and maximum timestamps in aspeed_df: 2021-01-11 08:50:00 2021-11-22 08:25:00
Minimum and maximum timestamps in trafficflow_df: 2021-01-11 08:50:00 2021-11-22 08:25:00
Minimum and maximum timestamps in carcount_df: 2021-01-11 08:50:01 2021-03-17 23:59:59
         Sensor Name_x     Variable_x Units_x         Timestamp_x  Value_x  \
0       PER_NE_N05111A  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:50:00     80.0   
1       PER_NE_N05111A  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:50:00     80.0   
2       PER_NE_N05111A  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:50:00     80.0   
3       PER_NE_N05111A  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:50:00     80.0   
4       PER_NE_N05111A  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:50:00     80.0   
...                ...            ...     ...                 ...      ...   
130427  PER_NE_N05171T  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:55:00     80.0   
130428  PER_NE_N05171T  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:55:00     80.0   
130429  PER_NE_N05171T  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:55:00     80.0   
130430  PER_NE_N05171T  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:55:00     80.0   
130431  PER_NE_N05171T  Average Speed    KmPH 2021-01-11 08:55:00     80.0   

                                          Time_Bin   Sensor Name_y  \
0       [2021-01-11 08:50:00, 2021-01-11 08:55:00)  PER_NE_N05111A   
1       [2021-01-11 08:50:00, 2021-01-11 08:55:00)  PER_NE_N05111A   
2       [2021-01-11 08:50:00, 2021-01-11 08:55:00)  PER_NE_N05111A   
3       [2021-01-11 08:50:00, 2021-01-11 08:55:00)  PER_NE_N05111A   
4       [2021-01-11 08:50:00, 2021-01-11 08:55:00)  PER_NE_N05111A   
...                                            ...             ...   
130427  [2021-01-11 08:55:00, 2021-01-11 09:00:00)  PER_NE_N05171T   
130428  [2021-01-11 08:55:00, 2021-01-11 09:00:00)  PER_NE_N05171T   
130429  [2021-01-11 08:55:00, 2021-01-11 09:00:00)  PER_NE_N05171T   
130430  [2021-01-11 08:55:00, 2021-01-11 09:00:00)  PER_NE_N05171T   
130431  [2021-01-11 08:55:00, 2021-01-11 09:00:00)  PER_NE_N05171T   

          Variable_y              Units_y         Timestamp_y  Value_y  \
0       Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:50:00      0.0   
1       Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:50:00      0.0   
2       Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:50:00      0.0   
3       Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:50:00      0.0   
4       Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:50:00      0.0   
...              ...                  ...                 ...      ...   
130427  Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:55:00      3.0   
130428  Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:55:00      3.0   
130429  Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:55:00      3.0   
130430  Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:55:00      3.0   
130431  Traffic Flow  Passenger Car Units 2021-01-11 08:55:00      3.0   

                       Sensor Name   Variable     Units           Timestamp  \
0            PER_PEOPLE_SL_A1231G1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:50:01   
1            PER_PEOPLE_GH_B1426A1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:50:05   
2       PER_PEOPLE_VAISALACCTV2394  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:50:25   
3            PER_PEOPLE_NC_B6918A1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:50:29   
4             PER_PEOPLE_GH_A167H1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:50:33   
...                            ...        ...       ...                 ...   
130427        PER_PEOPLE_NT_A189B2  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:59:25   
130428        PER_PEOPLE_NT_A191A1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:59:35   
130429        PER_PEOPLE_NC_A695F1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:59:36   
130430        PER_PEOPLE_NC_A167A1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:59:38   
130431       PER_PEOPLE_GH_B1296C1  Car Count  Vehicles 2021-01-11 08:59:40   

        Value  
0         0.0  
1         5.0  
2         0.0  
3         3.0  
4         2.0  
...       ...  
130427    1.0  
130428    3.0  
130429    1.0  
130430    3.0  
130431    3.0  

[130432 rows x 16 columns]
```

Is there a way I can avoid Cartesian product in this situation and if so how can I do that?